# PHP (Laravel 5.4) - As soon as a post hits a certain age, update entry in database

Tags: php, laravel, updating

I just need a little advice on how I should approach this.

Basically, the application consists of a bidding platform, where users can bid on an item until the post is 12 hours old. Then the status of the "post" is set to closed and bidding is no longer allowed. So, my question is:

What is the best way to be constantly looking for posts that are 12 hours old (needs to close at the exact second) and update the database? Is it ideal to just update the post once a user attempts to load it and perform the check then?

Comment: closed  = created_at + 12h so: To get a live posts = Posts.Where(created_at+12hours < NOW())

Comment: Do you need to flag it as closed? You can just compute if it's closed based on creation time.

Comment: @apokryfos is onto the right idea: updating the database isn't the important part. Your code just needs to know how to treat a post that is older than twelve hours versus one that is younger than twelve hours. You can calculate that cutoff on the fly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would not work.

Consider the scenario where you have an item that needs to be expired at `23:30`

If you depend on a user to access the item, then there's also a possibility where nobody will access the item and it will stay that way.

Laravel has a powerful `Queue` system where you can schedule jobs to be executed. So you can for e.g, schedule a job to run at exactly 12 hours after you create a new item.

So this should work:

```
$job = (new ExpireItem($item))
                ->delay(Carbon::now()->addHours(12));
```

More information in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues#delayed-dispatching)